# Azure Active Directory Company Branding - Can't Edit

Tags: azure, branding

I've configured Company Branding (Images, Text, etc.) using Azure Active Directory > Company branding > Configure, and works fine.

However, I can't find any way to actually go back and edit the branding (update/delete), etc.

When I go into Company branding now, it just shows a record with LOCALE as Default, and no edit button. And the Delete button is grayed out.

How can I either remove the branding I applied, or edit it (Ideally) to use different images, etc.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> When I go into Company branding now, it just shows a record with
>   LOCALE as Default, and no edit button. And the Delete button is grayed
>   out.

After you finish configuring, by default, the Delete button is grayed out. But if you want to change the image, you can click the Remove button and then you can update the new.
[image]

If your situation is different, please post your screenshot here.

Comment: Working now - before when I clicked on the record it didn't do anything. Logged out and back in, refreshed the page, and still nothing. Then all of a sudden it opened the edit screen - so all good now. Really don't know why it wouldn't work before. Thanks for your reply - appreciated.